# How can i make this grid layout group expand horizontally?

Tags: unity-game-engine, grid-layout, scrollable

I am building a Unity game, and want my child elements of my grid layout group to expand horizontally across so i can scroll through, rather then vertically. I have been playing around with the settings for awhile, but can't seem to make it work. I have attached some relevant images. Thank you!

[What i am looking for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BcKX.png)

[What it is doing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DKdF.png)

[Grid layout settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bba0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Go to constraint set the fix row count to 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HorizontalLayoutGroup` to stack your elements horizontally.